# Unable to show matplotlib runing in WSL2 Ubuntu virtual environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, pipenv, wsl-2

I am using WSL2 Ubuntu. I create virtual environment for each Python project with

```
pipenv shell
```

I want to run `matplotlib` in the terminal of this virtual environment (activated).

Here is a simple snippet:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

Of course, there are many threads talking about this error. I implemented the solutions, such as:

1 - Check `matplotlib.get_backend()`

This gives me `TkAgg`

2 - Install the `tk` stuff globally by (I can't install these stuff below in a Python virtual environment, clearly)

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev python-tk python3-tk
```

3 - Open file `matplotlibrc` and set `backend TkAgg`.

4 - Restart the terminal

All of those still do not work, with the same error message.
How do I run `matplotlib` code in a virtual enviroment in WSL2 Ubuntu to show the plot?

Comment: You're essentially trying to run a linux GUI app in Windows via WSL. This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps  -- If you need see your plot *right now*, I'd either save it to a PNG or convert this script to a jupyter notebook